# How to save path of a file and use the path in browse button in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-explorer, create-directory

In C# windows application, i have a textbox1 and "create folder" button and "Open created folder!" buttons.
when, i give a name to textbox1 and press "create folder", a folder create with that name. In next step i want to open the folder which i have created
The problem is that i dont know how to open that folder which i created! i can only open a directory before the name of my folder.
How can i get the path in "create folder" button and use this path for opening inside of the folder?
Here is my Code:

[image]

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create a folder

        var adr = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\aa\Desktop\test2\" + textBox1.Text);

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = (@"C:\Users\aa\Desktop\test2\"),
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "open"
        });
```

Comment: use FileName = (@"C:\Users\aa\Desktop\test2\" + textBox1.Text)

Comment: Thanks. and how can i open that folder with using of pictureBox name instead of textbox.text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the foleder's name to the path of the folder you want to open.

Chagne this:

```
FileName = (@"C:\Users\aa\Desktop\test2\")
```

To this:

```
FileName = (@"C:\Users\aa\Desktop\test2\" + textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks. and how can i open that folder with using of pictureBox name instead of textbox.text name?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by pictureBox name, but you can just replace textbox.text with any property/function/method that returns a string.